# About NSArray nil crash error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

How to avoid this crash error!Crash in main thread Log is

```
ProcessArray:()
ProcessArray == 0
-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3c4e1090
```

my code:

```
ProcessArray = [EventSheetDetailArray  valueForKey:@"Process"];
NSLog(@"ProcessArray:%@",ProcessArray);

if (ProcessArray.count > 0 ) {
    NSLog(@"ProcessArray != 0");
    [self ProcessJSONDateFormat];
}else{
    NSLog(@"ProcessArray == 0");
}
```

I change judge below!

```
id value = [EventSheetDetailArray valueForKey:@"Process"];
if ( ![[NSNull null] isEqual:value] )
{
    ProcessArray = value;
    NSLog(@"1111111");
}else{
    NSLog(@"2222222");
}
```

But always run NSLog(@"1111111") this line!
Regardless of whether any value!

Comment: You don't need to alloc->init your array in this implementation. your `EventSheetDetailArray` is returning `[NSNull null]` and not an array

Answer (score 4):

Validate the return value from [EventSheetDetailArray valueForKey:@"Process"]

```
id value = [EventSheetDetailArray valueForKey:@"Process"];
if ( ![[NSNull null] isEqual:value] )
{
    ProcessArray = value;
}
```

OR

```
id value = [EventSheetDetailArray valueForKey:@"Process"];
if ( [value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] )
{
    ProcessArray = value;
}
```

then you can call NSArray member functions, don't just assume it is NSArray..

Comment: To andykkt: I use if ( ![[NSNull null] isEqual:value] ) ,But log show -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3c4e1090

Comment: To andykkt:SORRY!I Konw -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3c4e1090 ,Because have other code error!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually quite simple.

```
if([ProcessArray count] != [NSNULL NULL]) {
    if (ProcessArray.count > 0 ) {
      NSLog(@"ProcessArray != 0");
     [self ProcessJSONDateFormat];
    }else {
      NSLog(@"ProcessArray == 0");
    }
}else {
      NSLog(@"NULL...insert some value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!I found the cause of the error,Because my other code have error, That caused crash main thread -[NSNull length] reason!

Answer (score 0):

If your array is empty then you can't check for count otherwise it will crash.I faced the same issue.Just use  "if(!(array==nil))".This is true when your array is empty otherwise it will move to else part.